# Update Numeric field without Decimal point and Zeros

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to update a numeric field. But the field can not have zeros after decimal point. But the table that I am trying to pull values contain data as  87.00,90.00,100.00 etc.. How do I update without decimal point and zeros?

Example :percentage is a numeric field.
Update value available 100.00,90.00 etc.

```
update table1 
  set percent =(tmpercent as integer) 
from table2
where table2.custid=table1.custoid;
```

;

gives error.

Table1:

```
CustID   Percent(numeric)
1           90
2           80
```

Table2:

```
CustomID  tmpPercent(varchar)
1              87.00
2              90.00
```

Comment: Please add the table definitions.

Answer (score 2):

i often use typecasting `::FLOAT::NUMERIC` to get rid of extra fraction zeros of numerics

or you can use `TRUNC()` function to force fraction truncation

try

```sql
update table1 
    set percent = tmpercent::FLOAT::NUMERIC 
from table2
where table2.custid=table1.custoid;
```

or

```sql
update table1 
    set percent = TRUNC(tmpercent::NUMERIC)
from table2
where table2.custid=table1.custoid;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is going to depend on how the `numeric` field is specified in the table. From here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html

> We use the following terms below: The precision of a numeric is the total count of significant digits in the whole number, that is, the number of digits to both sides of the decimal point. The scale of a numeric is the count of decimal digits in the fractional part, to the right of the decimal point. So the number 23.5141 has a precision of 6 and a scale of 4. Integers can be considered to have a scale of zero.

> NUMERIC(precision, scale)

So if your field has a scale > 0 then you will see 0 to the right of the decimal point, unless you set `scale` to 0.  As example:

```
create table numeric_test (num_fld numeric(5,2), num_fld_0 numeric(5,0));

insert into numeric_test (num_fld, num_fld_0) values ('90.0', '90.0');

select * from numeric_test ;
 num_fld | num_fld_0 
---------+-----------
   90.00 |        90

insert into numeric_test (num_fld, num_fld_0) values ('90.5', '90.5');

select * from numeric_test ;
 num_fld | num_fld_0 
---------+-----------
   90.00 |        90
   90.50 |        91

insert into numeric_test (num_fld, num_fld_0) values ('90.0'::float, '90.0'::float);

select * from numeric_test ;
 num_fld | num_fld_0 
---------+-----------
   90.00 |        90
   90.50 |        91
   90.00 |        90
```

Using `scale` 0 means you have basically created an integer field. If you have a `scale` > 0 then you are going to get decimals in the field.